# mysql group by display unique count of columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT ip_address,datetime,DATE(datetime) as thedate, count(DATE(datetime)) as visits
FROM articleview_logtable 
GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
```

this query works great it returns how many rows for each date.I want a query to find out the total of rows for each day without counting ip duplicates.
each row is inserted when someone visits the page that I made, the problem is if someonecomes back from the same ip I dont want to count them for that day as a new person.

Comment: Use DISTINCT to group duplicate `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ip_address)),datetime,DATE(datetime) as thedate, count(DATE(datetime)) as visits
FROM articleview_logtable 
GROUP BY DATE(datetime)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT ip_address, COUNT(DISTINCT(ip_address)) as visits, datetime,DATE(datetime) as thedate, 
FROM articleview_logtable 
GROUP BY DATE(datetime)
```